Calling base class from 2 levels of derived class
I wish to call an overridden base class function from 2 or 3 levels down.  For example
public class Level1
{
    public virtual void Encrypt(byte[] plain)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("level1");
    }
}

public class Level2: Level1
{
    public override void Encrypt(byte[] plain)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("level2");
        Console.WriteLine("Calling base class");
        base.Encrypt(plain);
    }
}

public class Level3: Level2
{
    public override void Encrypt(byte[] plain)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Level3");
        // Level2
        base.Encrypt(plain);
        // How do I call Encrypt from Level1?
        base.base.Encrypt(plain);
    }
}

The following end up with syntax errors
base.base.Encrypt(plain)
CryptECB.Encrypt(plain)

How do I call an overridden function from 2 or more levels of derivation?  So far as a workaround I've defined L1Encrypt in Level2 and called that from Level3 but it is messy as I may have to do this for various functions at different levels.

You can't - at least not without using reflection. This why Java-style single-inheritance (with no reification of the heirarchy either) is going out of fashion.

Can you post an example of how to do this with reflection?  I'm not too worried about fashion.  I would just prefer the code to be neat than fashionable.

I don't want to encourage bad ideas, or nonportable code (e.g. you can't use reflection in AOT code, for example). Instead why don't you share your actual source-files and the real problem you're trying to solve and we can tell you a better solution?

It's only a guess but it looks like you're trying to build some kind of pipelined logic. If that's the case, I'd advise using something designed to model such pipelines rather than thinking that class inheritance does or can be forced to do so. If you could tell us the actual problem to be solved we may be able to offer better suggestions.

Is "neat" some sort of belittlement for hack? If you don't use this like a inheritance chain why do you want his to be inherited classes at all? For me if you want to call the encrypt methods of the levels individually independent of the actual inheritance chain with a specific strategy then they should be individually classes and brought together by some sort of strategy pattern/class.

@cup what you're asking is a hack, not neat. Overriding means you want to replace the parent method entirely. You've already called Level1.Encrypt when you used base.Encrypt in Level3.Encrypt anyway. If you want to use the same method from multiple levels in the hierarchy create a separate protected method and call it as needed

Are you trying to use inheritance to build a workflow or pipeline of steps? In that case you're using the wrong concept. Inheritance specifies an is-a relation. A Level3 instance is a Level2 instance and can be used everywhere Level2 is used. .NET's cryptography and stream classes already allow creating a pipeline of processing steps, either by applying transforms or by wrapping one Stream class inside another.

While this really looks like a dupe, I would have been interested if we could help you with a better design to solve your underlying problem @cup? In a new question, perhaps?

Why do you need to call level 1 function from level 3? You've called level 2, and that called level 1.

I have a different function at level 3 that needs the level 1 version: not the level 2 version.  Not shown in the simplified example - level 1 only does 1 iteration.  Level 2 does multiple iterations based on some criteria specific to level 2.  I need to use the level 1 version in some places and the level 2 in other places.

@PanagiotisKanavos Yes, it may be a hack but I find it easier to understand than wrapping stuff up in streams, which is next to impossible to follow.  This is just legacy bug in C#4.x which has to be corrected so it gives the right result.  In 3 places, It is calling the parent implementation when it should be calling the grandparent implementation.  Currently, I'm using a separate routine in the parent to call the grandparent.  Just looks like a bad excuse for a faster processor.

Not saying there is a bug is C#.  There is a bug in the code that I'm correcting.

There's no native C# way to call the grandparent like this. End of story. If you want multiple classes to call the same code, put it in a separate method. It's not whether the code looks simpler to you either - C# uses several well established design patterns like the Decorator pattern for streams. That's what allows you to wrap a FileStream into a GZipStream and then a CryptoStream to store compressed and encrypted data directly to disk.

If you insist on making such a call, check the duplicate question. You'll either have to use reflection or modify Level2 at least to forward the call to Level1.Encrypt

My original solution was a modified level 2.  I was just wondering if there was a more direct way of doing it as I've never come across a such a situation before.  Reflection looks too complex - have to think of the people who are maintaining this so I'll just stick to a modified level 2.
